# how can i authenticate logged in user in django generic views?

Tags: django, django-2.0

Hello to Stack Overflow community,
I had created login and logout functions in django views.py hence i had successfully achieved login and logout methods also but i am confusing know that how can i pass data of this logged in user details to my class based views in views.py because i want to give access to my class based views only if user login happened

### views.py

```
def admin_login(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            context['user'] = request.user
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            context['error'] = 'Provide Valid Credentials'
            return render(request, "secret_template.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "secret_template.html", context)


def admin_logout(request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('secretview')
```

### i want to authenticate below view only if user logged in

```
class index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret_template.html'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) in your view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class index(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('admin_login') # or whatever
    template_name = 'aapp/index.html'
```

Comment: Dear Daniel it worked thanks for guiding me, but how can i get this current user deatils to my index view with this login....?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you want to do with them? Have you read any of the docs on using the auth framework?

Comment: Daniel Roseman thanks no problem i will go through the docs where i am not clear but thnaks for teaching me

Comment: @naniraju, you need the `request` field in your View object.  in any method, for example `get_context`, access `self.request.user` as you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Following Django documentation you'll find some generic examples fitting your request:
For function based views you can simply use the [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    return Something
```

For class based views you have an example  with [method_decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'secret.html'
```

edit: 
I cannot comment, so I add this here:
You can handle a user instance from [request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) inside your views methods.

Comment: important to note that this decorator does not work on class based views, and one should use the solution stated above